# ¿Cómo evitar que el resultado de una función se junte al título?

Tags: css, bootstrap, jquery-ui, font-awesome, animate.css

Estoy haciendo una web médica para la escuela. En mi avance tengo el siguiente código que *calcula la cantidad de **insulina** recomendada por un médico*. El cálculo está hecho en *JavaScript*.

El formulario no se ve bien pero he obtenido un problema debido a mis estilos (*CSS*) y/o el *DOM* de mi *HTML*. Lo que ocurre es que el resultado choca con el título de la página y quiero ponerlo **centrado** para que quede más agradable a la vista.

```js
var usuario = prompt("¿Cuales son las calorias consumidas?");
var cal = prompt("¿Cual es la cantidad de insulina recomendada por su medico?");
var peso = parseInt(usuario);
var planeta = prompt(
  "Oprime del 1 al 10 si estas seguro, caso contrario Cancelar \n La cantidad de Calorias ingerias es de: " +
    usuario +
    " y la Cantidad de Insulina recomendada por su medico es de: " +
    cal
);
var g_calorias = 1.8;
var g_masa = 2.7;
var peso_final;
if (peso >= 105) {
  if (planeta >= 1 && planeta < 11) {
    peso_final = peso + cal / g_calorias - 100;
    peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);
    document.write(
      "\n\n La cantidad de insulina a ingerir es <strong> " +
        peso_final +
        " Ml </strong>"
    );
  } else if (planeta == 34) {
    peso_final = peso * g_jupiter / g_calorias;
    peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);
    document.write(
      " Tu peso en Jupiter es <strong> " + peso_final + " Kilos </strong>"
    );
  } else {
    document.write("No estas siendo muy honesto.");
  }
  peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);
} else {
  document.write(
    "La cantidad de calorias ingresadas no constan como una comida"
  );
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>APP INSULINA</title>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.boomcdn.com/libs/animate-css/3.7.0/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <div id="myDiv">
    <!--HEADER-->
    <div class="header">
      <div class="bg-color">
        <header id="main-header">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">APP INSULINA<span class="logo-dec"></span></a>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="banner-info text-center wow fadeIn delay-05s">

              </div>
              <div class="overlay-detail">
                <a href="#feature"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

He probado añadiendo saltos de líneas a la ejecución pero eso es insuficiente.

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta, por favor edita y muestra de formas clara lo que deseas mostrar y como se encima el contenido. Saludos

Comment: Edité tu pregunta, acepta los cambios, por favor. Te sugiero también que agregues los estilos porque es lo que le da forma a la página y que revises tus divs y el form ya que este nunca abre.

Answer (score 2):

**Editado**

El problema esta en tu html, esta totalmente mal. Tienes el `div.wrapper` dentro del `div.header`, además de que cierras una etiqueta `form` la cual no existe su apertura. Y cierras demasiados divs inexistentes por eso el renderizado se ve mal.

Además de que no deberías usar `document.write`

Prueba de esta forma

```js
var usuario = prompt("¿Cuales son las calorias consumidas?");
var cal = prompt("¿Cual es la cantidad de insulina recomendada por su medico?");
var peso = parseInt(usuario);
var planeta = prompt(
  "Oprime del 1 al 10 si estas seguro, caso contrario Cancelar \n La cantidad de Calorias ingerias es de: " +
    usuario +
    " y la Cantidad de Insulina recomendada por su medico es de: " +
    cal
);
var g_calorias = 1.8;
var g_masa = 2.7;
var peso_final;
var output = [];
if (peso >= 105) {
  if (planeta >= 1 && planeta < 11) {
    peso_final = peso + cal / g_calorias - 100;
    peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);
     output.push(
      "\n\n La cantidad de insulina a ingerir es <strong> " +
        peso_final +
        " Ml </strong>"
    );
  } else if (planeta == 34) {
    peso_final = peso * g_jupiter / g_calorias;
    peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);
    output.push(
      " Tu peso en Jupiter es <strong> " + peso_final + " Kilos </strong>"
    );
  } else {
    output.push("No estas siendo muy honesto.");
  }
  peso_final = parseInt(peso_final);
} else {
  output.push(
    "La cantidad de calorias ingresadas no constan como una comida"
  );
}
document.querySelector(".row").innerHTML = output.join('')
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>APP INSULINA</title>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="loader"></div>
  <div id="myDiv">
    <!-- open header -->
    <div class="header">
      <div class="bg-color">
        <header id="main-header">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">APP INSULINA<span class="logo-dec"></span></a>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- close header -->
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```